# Can I refer to a field within the same Django model?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to design some Django models and neither the official docs nor Stack Overflow have yielded an answer yet.

The problem is within the Student model: a student has an English name, and a non-English name (e.g. Chinese). However, they often prefer to be called one or the other, and also, their Parent calls them one or the other (and sometimes the Parent has a different preference :)

I want to store this preference in the Student model. Right now I'm storing a text value that indicates the preferred name for both the Student and Parent:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ENGLISH_NAME = 'E'
    OTHER_NAME = 'O'

    PREFERRED_NAME_CHOICES = (
        (ENGLISH_NAME, 'English Name'),
        (OTHER_NAME, 'Other Name (any language)'),
    )
    PREFERRED_NAME_FIELDS = {
        ENGLISH_NAME: 'first_name_english',
        OTHER_NAME: 'first_name_other',
    }

    first_name_english = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name_other = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    child_preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PREFERRED_NAME_CHOICES)
    parent_preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PREFERRED_NAME_CHOICES)
```

I think that's ugly. Is there a better way to refer to a field within the same model, other than storing some value in the database?

Thanks :)

Comment: I would just keep things simple, and store the flags in `child_preferred` and `parent_preferred` - just the way  you have declared it. If you are storing redundant data in the database, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly as good as it gets!

An improvement you could make here would be to use `BooleanField`s, as you're only storing a flag, and not actually a 1-char text value which is a lot bigger than a single bit.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! I definitely don't want to store redundant data (as  karthikr mentioned). I guess I'll go with this for now, but I think that's a good idea to use a BooleanField instead. Cheers :)